# How to fetch group memberships from an AAD group

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch all group memberships from an AAD. I have to name of the parent group I want to look for, but I need to fetch the users that are in sub groups of that parent. I've tried may things on the Microsoft docs, but I can't find the right request to find those groups.

This is a try:

```
var groups = await graphClient.Groups.Request().Filter($"startswith(displayName, '{Se_groupName}')").GetAsync(); //Fetch the parent group
var groupMembers = await graphClient.Groups[groups.FirstOrDefault().Id].Members.Request().GetAsync(); //Try to fetch the groups inside the first group, but its always empty
```

I was wondering is there a request like:

```
graphClient.Groups[groups.FirstOrDefault().Id].groupMemberships
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the nested groups and users you can use the `transitiveMembers` endpoint

[List group transitive members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/transitiveMembers`

Comment: Sorry if I'm late a bit, but I tried it this morning and it worked really well. Thanks!